Is this hypercomplex system sound? If so what is it called?
sorry for the bad image quality, I had to improvise
Definiton of a hypercomplex number [it's in the tag] :

A hypercomplex number is an element of a finite-dimensional algebra over the real numbers that is unital and distributive (but not necessarily associative).

The defining properties of this system are as follows:
$\ ij=-j,$ $\ ji=-i,$ $\ i^2=j^2=-1 $
One thing to note is this system is neither commutative nor anti-commutative
$\ ji=-i, $ $\ ij=-j,$ $\ -ij=j$
$\ -i\neq-j\neq j $
$\therefore ji\neq ij\neq-ji$
the question has already been stated in the title, if there is anything missing than I will edit it accordingly

If this is assumed to be associative then
$$
  ij = jiij = 1
$$
and so
$$
  -j = iij = i.
$$
But
$$
  1 = -jj = ij = -j
$$
but also
$$
  1 = -ii = ji = -i.
$$
Thus $1 = -1$ and your system is inconsistent.

Because the algebra is not associative it can't be the trivial algebra.
Note that the algebra is spanned by $1,i,j$.
Suppose now that $j = \alpha i$ for some scalar $\alpha$. Then
$$
  -i = (\alpha i)i = -\alpha^2
$$
and $i = \alpha^2$, making the algebra trivial. This is impossible, so $i$ and $j$ are linearly independent.
Suppose now that $1 = \alpha i + \beta j$ for some scalars $\alpha,\beta$. Then
$$
  1 = (\alpha i + \beta j)^2 = -\alpha^2 - \beta^2 - \alpha\beta(i + j).
$$
This implies that one of $\alpha, \beta$ must be nonzero. Thus
$$
  1 = \frac{-\alpha\beta}{1+\alpha^2+\beta^2}(i+j).
$$
Because $i,j$ are linearly independent, this implies
$$
  \alpha = \beta = \frac{-\alpha^2}{1+2\alpha^2} \implies 2\alpha^3 + \alpha^2 + \alpha = 0
$$
and because $\alpha$ cannot be zero we get
$$
  2\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 = 0.
$$
The discriminant of this quadratic equation is
$$
  1 - 4(2)(1) < 0
$$
so there are no real solutions, which contradicts the assumption that $1$ is a linear combination of $i,j$.
Thus $1,i,j$ is a basis for the algebra, and we can define multiplication by
$$
  (\alpha + \beta i + \gamma j)(\alpha' + \beta' i + \gamma' j) = \alpha\alpha' - \beta\beta' - \gamma\gamma' + (\alpha\beta' + \beta\alpha' - \gamma\beta')i + (\alpha\gamma' + \gamma\alpha' - \beta\gamma')j.$$
This multiplication satisfies the requisite identities; this proves that the algebra is consistent and unique.

Simpler: $\ [\color{#c00}{-j} = ij = \color{#0af}{\bf 1}]^2 \Rightarrow,  \color{#c00}{\bf {-}!1} = \color{#0af}{\bf 1}\ \ \ $

On what basis do we assume this? Is there a deeper reason it must be associative, or that this cannot count as simply just proof of a specific property by contradiction? If not then isn't it in the definition of a hyper-complex number that it is not necessarily associative?

@AnonymousPoster It can be whatever you want it to be, "hypercomplex" is not formally defined as far as I know. But you really need to prove your system is consistent even then, it's not something you can just assume. I suspect Hurwitz's theorem is applicable here, in which case your system is inconsistent.

You still haven't answered why you assumed it's associative but what you said recently is a more useful answer, is it ok if I add that in to your previous post? Also for clarification while I can do mathematics with quaternions and duals relatively well (I was gifted with a pretty ok 4d visualization at a weirdly young age so I can just graph it, really), I often struggle with the other hypercomplex systems, which why I'm asking for help online understanding this subject.

@AnonymousPoster No, I don't think you should add anything to the answer body about Hurwitz's theorem unless you prove it applies. In fact, it doesn't: I've added a proof that your algebra is uniquely defined. I've also come to the realization that consistency is trivial: writing $S = {\pm,\pm j,\pm i}$ and assuming all these elements are distinct, as long as the binary operation $S\times S \to S$ defined by your rules is consistent with $1$ being the identity and $\pm1$ being scalars then it automatically defines a 3D algebra. Your rules do do this...

...and what I've proved is that there is no lower dimensional algebra satisfying these rules. As for "why assume associativity": (1) I proved that your system cannot be associative, which seems quite important; and (2) probably because "anything and everything" is boring. Even if you don't want associativity, you probably want some weaker form of associativity so that your algebra is worth studying.
